# Color cycling through the rainbow using RGB variables not transitioning smoothly

Tags: javascript

I have it so that the a circle being drawn will slowly transition through the rainbow as the circle completes. The first two work nicely. After that though, it stops slowly changing and just snaps to one shade until the next one. Can you please tell me what I've done incorrectly? It's probably something really obvious :C

```
function setcolor() {
    if (degrees <= 60) {
            var g = Math.floor(255 * (degrees/60));
            color = "rgb(255, "+ g +", 0)";
        }
            else if (degrees <= 120) {
            var r = Math.floor(255 / (degrees/60));
            color = "rgb("+ r +", 255, 0)";
        }
            else if (degrees <= 180) {
            var b = Math.floor(255 * (degrees/60));
            color = "rgb(0, 255, "+ b +")";
        }
            else if (degrees <= 240) {
            (g = Math.floor(255 /(degrees/60)));
            color = "rgb(0, "+ g +", 255)";
        }
            else if (degrees <= 300) {
            (r = Math.floor(255 * (degrees/60)));
            color = "rgb("+ r +", 0, 255)";
        }
            else if (degrees <= 360) {
            (g = Math.floor(255 / (degrees/60)));
            color = "rgb(255, "+ g +", 0)";
        }
}
```

Comment: where "degrees" comes from?. Can you show us how you are using this function?

Comment: You would probably be best off using hsv rather than rgb.

Comment: Degrees is the amount the circle is drawn. I can give you a link to the whole code if you like.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/Hrichards/codebits/nRFD34/edit

Comment: You haven't shown how you use the color value to update the DOM. Have you tried logging the color values to make sure they look right?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your last block. It is called as the `else` to `degrees <= 300`, so we know that at a minimum `degrees` will be 301. Let's just call it 300 for ease of calculations.

```
g = Math.floor(255 / (degrees / 60));
```

This results in `255 / (300 / 60) = 255 / 5 = 51` - This is not what you'd expect, as for a smooth transition it should go from 255 to 0 (or 0 to 255).

The reason for this is because your `degrees / 60` should be transitioning from `0` to `1`, which it only does in the very first step. Try `(degrees - 300) / 60`, as this fits the range.

You will also notice that for a *smooth* transition, you want to use `255 * (1-(degrees-300)/60)`

All of this is moot, however, when you can just do this:

```
color = "hsl("+degrees+"deg, 100%, 50%)";
```